# Errors attempting to run GPT detector under Ubuntu 22.04 WSL

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda

While the [OpenAI detector](https://huggingface.co/openai-detector) has been useful in identifying content that is created by ChatGPT and other OpenAI-based models, as usage increases (especially by users here on Stack Exchange sites), it's been down more and more frequently.

After installing it locally per the project [README](https://github.com/openai/gpt-2-output-dataset/tree/master/detector), I receive the following error when attempting to run it from the repo directory using `python -m detector.server ../gpt-2-models/detector-base.pt`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ntd/src/gpt-2-output-dataset/detector/server.py", line 120, in <module>
    fire.Fire(main)
  File "/home/ntd/src/venv/openai-detector/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 141, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "/home/ntd/src/venv/openai-detector/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 475, in _Fire
    component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace(
  File "/home/ntd/src/venv/openai-detector/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 691, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ntd/src/gpt-2-output-dataset/detector/server.py", line 89, in main
    model.load_state_dict(data['model_state_dict'])
  File "/home/ntd/src/venv/openai-detector/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1671, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for RobertaForSequenceClassification:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "roberta.embeddings.position_ids".
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "roberta.pooler.dense.weight", "roberta.pooler.dense.bias".
```

I attempted to change `transformers==2.9.1` per comments in [this issue](https://github.com/openai/gpt-2-output-dataset/issues/35), but then `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And one more solution, in case you can't use my [Docker-based answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1465456/1165986) for some reason.  I believe this should replace my [original solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1448783/1165986) as the preferred method.

Using the [Dockerfile](https://huggingface.co/spaces/openai/openai-detector/blob/main/Dockerfile) for the HuggingFace space as a guide, I've been able to reproduce this on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.  I'm running it on WSL, but thanks to @cocomac for confirming this also works on stock Debian. It should run on any recent Debian-based distribution:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install -y \
    git \
    make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm \
    libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev git-lfs  \
    ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 cmake libgl1-mesa-glx

git lfs install
cd ~
git clone https://huggingface.co/spaces/openai/openai-detector
cd openai-detector

PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
source ~/.bashrc
PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH

pyenv install 3.7.5
# ^ Takes a while

pyenv global 3.7.5
pyenv rehash

python --version
# Confirm 3.7.5

pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install --no-cache-dir \
    datasets \
    huggingface-hub "protobuf<4" "click<8.1"

pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
# Ignore dependency errors, as it still appears to work

python -m detector.server detector-base.pt --port 7860
```

For future launches, add the following to something like a `webui.sh` script:

```
PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH
pyenv global 3.7.5
pyenv rehash
cd ~/openai-detector
python -m detector.server detector-base.pt --port 7860
```

Answer (score 13):

***<sup>Leaving this answer in place since it still contains useful information, but I've added an easier method in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1465462/1165986).  If you have Docker Desktop, you can also use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1465456/1165986). Both of the newer answers have the advantage of strictly following the original HuggingSpace implementation, which this answer lacked.</sup>***

---

The primary problem here seems to be resolved by using `transformers==2.5.1` for me (as opposed to 2.9.1), but I also needed the Rust compiler (and `build-essential`) to build it.  Most of this, at least starting with step 11, may be applicable to a non-WSL Ubuntu as well.  However, there are also a few additional dependencies for CUDA (and I can't entirely be sure which, since I don't have a pure-Ubuntu GPU system on which to test).

Here are the complete steps I used to install on Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL.  Note that you *can* simplify it quite a bit, by either not setting up a special distribution for the detector, not setting up a Python `venv`, or even skipping both.  Honestly, doing both is overkill in terms of "isolation", but the steps are all here depending how you want to handle it:

1. Registered a new Ubuntu 22.04 WSL distribution with `ubuntu2204.exe` from PowerShell.  None previously existed, for reasons you'll see below.
2. Added username and password when requested.
3. Ran the normal, initial `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`.
4. Set the default username using `/etc/wsl.conf` per [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).
5. Exited Ubuntu
6. `wsl --shutdown`
7. Created a directory for my "openai-detector" instance:

   ```
   mkdir D:\WSL\instances\openai-detector
   ```
8. Copied the just-created Ubuntu 22.04 instance to a new distribution named `openai-detector`:

   ```
   wsl --import --vhd openai-detector D:\wsl\instances\openai-detector\ $env:localappdata\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx --version 2
   ```
9. Removed the `ubuntu-22.04` distribution since I can always create another one on demand when needed (as above).  However, please only do this if you are sure that this is the one you just created and that there are no files that you need from it.  This is an irreversible, destructible operation.  I'm honestly a bit nervous every time I do it, since there's the chance I'll accidentally use the wrong distribution name.  Just ... *be careful*:

   ```
   wsl --unregister ubuntu-22.04
   ```
10. Started the new `openai-detector` distribution created above:

    ```
    wsl ~ -d openai-detector
    ```
11. Installed `rustup` and `build-essential`:

    ```
    curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
    source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
    sudo apt install build-essential
    ```
12. Set up virtual environment:

    ```
    sudo apt install python3-venv
    python3 -m venv ~/src/venv/openai-detector
    source ~/src/venv/openai-detector/bin/activate
    ```
13. Clone the detector and download the model files:

    ```
    cd ~/src
    git clone https://github.com/openai/gpt-2-output-dataset.git
    mkdir gpt-2-models
    cd gpt-2-models
    wget https://openaipublic.azureedge.net/gpt-2/detector-models/v1/detector-base.pt
    # and/or
    wget https://openaipublic.azureedge.net/gpt-2/detector-models/v1/detector-large.pt
    ```
14. Modify the requirements to use Transformers 2.5.1:

    ```
    editor ~/src/gpt-2-output-dataset/requirements.txt
    ```

    Change the `transformers` line to:

    ```
    transformers==2.5.1
    ```
15. Install requirements:

    ```
    pip install wheel
    cd ~/src/gpt-2-output-dataset
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    ```
16. Run:

    ```
    python -m detector.server ../gpt-2-models/detector-base.pt
    ```

After initial installation, all that should be required in the future to start is:

```
wsl ~ -d openai-detector
cd ~/src/gpt-2-output-dataset
source ~/src/venv/openai-detector/bin/activate
python -m detector.server ../gpt-2-models/detector-base.pt
```

A local copy of OpenAI Detector should be running on `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving my other answer in place since it's useful to understand how to set things up "manually", but the recent addition of HuggingSpace's *"Run with Docker"* makes this far easier.

If you have Docker *Desktop* installed in Ubuntu (WSL or not), you can start up the OpenAI-Detector in a container:

- First, make sure you have [`containerd` enabled for Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/blog/extending-docker-integration-with-containerd/). This is currently a beta feature in Docker Desktop -- To enable, open the Docker Desktop Dashboard and go to *Settings* -> *Features in development* -> *Beta features* and select *"Use containerd for pulling and storing images"*.

  Without this in place, I received an error when attempting to pull the Docker image from HuggingFace.  Note that I have not found a way to enable this in Docker *Engine* at this point.
- With that in place, I was able to run the OpenAI-Detector with:

  ```
  docker run -it --rm --gpus=all -p 7860:7860 --platform=linux/amd64 registry.hf.space/openai-openai-detector:latest
  ```

Notes:

- This image consumes 5.84GB of disk space.
- The image is, unfortunately, based on Ubuntu 18.04, which will soon reach EoSS on May 31.
- `--rm` is optional, but recommended so that the container is removed after exiting.
- `--gpus=all` is also optional since the image doesn't seem to *require* GPU support.
- You can, of course, modify the port number being used by changing the first `7860` to the desired port (e.g. `-p 80:7860`).